# Ошибка 'int' object is not iterable

Tags: python, python-3.x, sqlite, telegram-bot, бот

Необходимо вытаскивать переменной id человека и заносить в базу но не выходит.
вот код

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
import random
import telebot
import sqlite3
from telebot.types import Message

TOKEN = '1034247492:AAF7bBQAoNr3-Zw6GKJV_Niu1G7a23w6qcI'
bot = telebot.TeleBot(TOKEN)

@bot.message_handler(commands=['info'])

def send_welcome(message):
    global userId
    userId = message.from_user.id
    print(userId)
    bot.reply_to(message, "Welcome")
    create_db()



def create_db():
    conn = sqlite3.connect("id_base.db")
    cur = conn.cursor()
    cur.executemany("INSERT INTO id_base VALUES (?)", userId)
    conn.commit()


bot.polling(timeout=1/2)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Метод [executemany](https://docs.python.org/3.8/library/sqlite3.html#sqlite3.Cursor.executemany) принимает список контейнеров (например, список), что будут добавлены в таблицу, а у вас там `userId`, являющийся числом (`int`):

```
cur.executemany("INSERT INTO id_base VALUES (?)", userId)
```

Измените на [execute](https://docs.python.org/3.8/library/sqlite3.html#sqlite3.Cursor.execute) и передавайте туда контейнер, например:

```
cur.execute("INSERT INTO id_base VALUES (?)", [userId])
```

---

**PS.**

Вот так выглядит пример входных данных для `executemany`:

```
persons = [
    ("Hugo", "Boss"),
    ("Calvin", "Klein")
]
con.executemany("insert into person(firstname, lastname) values (?, ?)", persons)
```

В таблицу будут добавлены две записи.

---

А вот так будет выглядеть для одной записи используя `execute`:

```
con.execute("insert into person(firstname, lastname) values (?, ?)", ("Hugo", "Boss"))

# Можно так:
con.execute("insert into person(firstname, lastname) values (?, ?)", ["Hugo", "Boss"])
```

Comment: Огромное спасибо вы мне очень помогли. Можно какой ваш контакт для связи?

Comment: @ДанилИлюшенко, [чтобы поблагодарить автора ответа, проголосуйте за ответ или отметьте его как решение](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers). Помогаю только в рамках этого сайта, если будут проблемы, то создавайте вопросы :)